# Chainer: custome sigmoid activation function

Tags: python, neural-network, autoencoder, chainer

I want to implement the following sigmoid function with a custom slope parameter k.

```py
y = f(x)= 1/ ( 1+exp(-1*k*x))
gradient gy = k * f(x)*(1-f(x))
```

I want to use this in my autoencoder. How do I implement this in Chainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `k` is constant (i.e., a hyperparameter), `F.sigmoid(k * x)` should just work.

If `k` is a parameter that should be learned in the same way as other weights, you may want to subclass a link like [L.PReLU](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/links/activation/prelu.py), and use it just like other links, e.g. `L.Linear` and `L.Convolution2D`. You can still implement the `forward` method of the link like the above simple expression.

Answer (score 0):

An activation function should be a subclass of `Chainer.FunctionNode` ([FunctionNode docs](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.FunctionNode.html)). An example of this is the [Swish](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.functions.swish.html) function provided by chainer library. You can observe its source [here](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/d297a1787ebb35cfce279dde0df64dd2feba4327/chainer/functions/activation/swish.py#L31) and clone it (or any other function such as [tanh](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/d297a1787ebb35cfce279dde0df64dd2feba4327/chainer/functions/activation/tanh.py#L15)) to make necessary changes to its forward and backward operation declaration to fit it to your needs.